# Check of differentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We want to check differentiability of $x^\frac{1}{3}$ at $x=0$.

For that I tried to find the left derivative and the right derivative and I discovered they are not equal.

But at $x=0$ the curve is smooth.

What can we say about differentiability?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2sWU.jpg)

Comment: Your first calculation has gone wrong. It comes out the same as the second as $\infty$.

Comment: @almagest i have written wrong in 3 step pf rhd but it is 0 only. You can see 2 step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small mistake in your calculations. The right hand and left hand derivatives are respectively
$$f'_+(x)=\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{h^{1/3}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^+}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{h^{2}}}=+\infty$$
$$f'_{-}(x)=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{h^{1/3}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^-}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{h^{2}}}=+\infty$$
The two limits exist and coincide, but they are not finite.

This is an example of a non differentiable function in $0$: for the derivative to be defined, both the right **and** the left limit of the derivative must **exist**,  **be finite** and **coincide**. In this case, both limits exist and coincide, but their value is not finite.

You can see this pretty clearly by graphing the function.

[image]

As you get closer to the origin, the tangent line to the graph tends to become vertical: this means that the derivative is not bounded in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: but the curve is smooth

Comment: @koolman What does smooth mean for you?

Comment: there is no sharp edge.

Comment: Unluckily, this is not a mathematical definition. This can be formalized: as a parametric curve in $\mathbb R^2$ the curve $\gamma(t)=(t, t^{\frac13})$ is in fact smooth: its derivative in $(0,0)$ is $(1,0)$. This is not the definition of smooth function: for a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ the graph must both be smooth and not have points in which the tangent line is vertical. This is kind of intuitive: if you imagine the derivative as a ratio $\frac{\text{heigth}}{\text{step}}$, this quantity is not defined if the tangent is vertical.